# How can I start my own university in Azerbaijan?

Tags: licensing, education, azerbaijan

I couldn't find much information for Azerbaijan but it looks like I need some sort of license from the government. How can I start my own university in **Azerbaijan** and what do I need to do so?

Comment: Step 1 - hire a lawyer

Comment: This is not a real question, but more a "how to"-request involving way too much information which could be considered off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Law on Education is [here](http://edu.gov.az/en/page/72/5244), and Article 16 states the licensing and accreditation requirements. The duration of the license depends on who is applying:

> Private and municipal educational institutions founded by the
>   individuals and legal entities of the Azerbaijan Republic are issued
>   special permits (license) for a 5-year period. The educational
>   institutions founded by the foreign individuals and legal entities are
>   issued special permits (license) for not less than 3 years.

Articles 22-23 apply to universities.

The executive agencies in charge of licensing are the Ministries of [Education](http://www.edu.gov.az/) and Economics, the former being most in charge. [As you can see they](http://edu.gov.az/az/page/348) only speak in broad terms about their obligations and powers, and do not say what their legal requirements or process is, suggesting it is highly discretionary.